# Dynamic Heap Memory in x86 Assembly MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

The following example I have found in Kip Irvine's Assembly x86 book uses dynamic memory allocation to repeatedly allocate large blocks of memory until the heap size is exceeded. I have modified some parts of the code by including the `WriteWindowsMsg` procedure because for some odd reason, I am receiving an error that this procedure does not exist. Here is the modified code:

```
; Heap Test #2 (Heaptest2.asm)
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data

HANDLE TEXTEQU <DWORD>

HeapCreate PROTO,
flOptions:DWORD, ; heap allocation options
dwInitialSize:DWORD, ; initial heap size, in bytes
dwMaximumSize:DWORD ; maximum heap size, in bytes

LocalFree PROTO,
pErrorMsg:DWORD 




FormatMessage PROTO,
FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER: DWORD,
messageID: DWORD, 
messageID: BYTE,
pErrorMsg: DWORD



HeapDestroy PROTO,
hHeap:DWORD ; heap handle


HeapAlloc PROTO,
hHeap:HANDLE, ; handle to existing heap block
HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY:DWORD, ; heap allocation control flags
BLOCK_SIZE:DWORD ; number of bytes to allocate


HeapFree PROTO,
hHeap:HANDLE,
dwFlags:DWORD,
lpMem:DWORD



HEAP_START = 2000000 ; 2 MByte

HEAP_MAX = 400000000 ; 400 MByte
BLOCK_SIZE = 500000 ; .5 MByte
hHeap HANDLE ? ; handle to the heap
pData DWORD ? ; pointer to block
str1 BYTE 0dh,0ah,"Memory allocation failed",0dh,0ah,0
HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY DWORD ?
WriteWindowsMsg_1 BYTE "Error ",0 
WriteWindowsMsg_2 BYTE ": ",0 
pErrorMsg DWORD ? 
messageId DWORD ? 


.code

main PROC

INVOKE HeapCreate, 0,HEAP_START, HEAP_MAX
.IF eax == NULL ; failed?
    call WriteWindowsMsg
    call Crlf
    jmp quit
.ELSE
    mov hHeap,eax ; success
.ENDIF
    mov ecx,2000 ; loop counter
    L1: call allocate_block ; allocate a block
.IF Carry? ; failed?
    mov edx,OFFSET str1 ; display message
    call WriteString
    jmp quit
.ELSE ; no: print a dot to
    mov al,'.' ; show progress
    call WriteChar
.ENDIF
;call free_block ; enable/disable this line
loop L1
quit:
    INVOKE HeapDestroy, hHeap ; destroy the heap
.IF eax == NULL ; failed?
    call WriteWindowsMsg ; yes: error message
    call Crlf
.ENDIF
exit
main ENDP


allocate_block PROC USES ecx
; allocate a block and fill with all zeros.
INVOKE HeapAlloc, hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, BLOCK_SIZE
.IF eax == NULL
    stc ; return with CF = 1
.ELSE
    mov pData,eax ; save the pointer
    clc ; return with CF = 0
.ENDIF
ret
allocate_block ENDP


free_block PROC USES ecx
INVOKE HeapFree, hHeap, 0, pData
ret
free_block ENDP




WriteWindowsMsg PROC USES eax edx 

call GetLastError 
mov messageId, eax 
mov edx, OFFSET WriteWindowsMsg_1 
call WriteString 
call WriteDec 
mov edx, OFFSET WriteWindowsMsg_2 
call WriteString 

INVOKE FormatMessage, FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER + \
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, messageID, NULL, 
    ADDR pErrorMsg, NULL, NULL 

mov edx, pErrorMsg 
call WriteString 

INVOKE LocalFree, pErrorMsg 

ret 
WriteWindowsMsg ENDP



END main
```

The following result I am getting is:

```
 Assembling: bobnew.asm
bobnew.asm(122) : error A2136: too many arguments to INVOKE
bobnew.asm(122) : error A2114: INVOKE argument type mismatch : argument : 3
bobnew.asm(122) : error A2006: undefined symbol : FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER

bobnew.asm(122) : error A2114: INVOKE argument type mismatch : argument : 1
bobnew.asm(114) : error A2006: undefined symbol : GetLastError
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong on my code? Thanks

Comment: 1) You added the wrong tag. This is apparently not related to C. 2) We are not a debugging service. Read  [ask].

Comment: Did you actually read the error messages? You can usually trust them to tell you exactly what is wrong. And you seem to be confusing argument names and constants, like `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every current `irvine32.lib` contains `WriteWindowsMsg`. Something went wrong with your installation.

Get `irvine32.inc` and `irvine32.lib` from [Kip Irvine's homepage](http://www.kipirvine.com/asm/examples/index.htm) (*"...link library..."*) and make sure the assembler uses that `irvine32.inc` and the linker uses that `irvine32.lib`.

Take a look at [Irvine's installation hints](http://www.kipirvine.com/asm/) (*"Getting started with MASM..."*).

I can't get your error messages on my system. `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` is used in your prototype of `FormatMessage` as a name for a parameter and in the `invoke` call as a constant. If the constant is not defined anywhere else (e.g in a -lib file) it is unknown. I don't know why your system cannot find `GetLastError`.